# Create or replace from the model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, I would like to be able to have a model that checks if a value for a column `signature` already exists, if it does not, save it, if it does, update the existing model and then exit out. This **has** to be a model solution. I cannot use controller logic to achieve this, it has to be automatic.

I have tried using filters like `before_create` or `before_save`, but it doesn't seem like there is a clean way to stop the filter chain and update an existing record by those means. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by signature?

Comment: Yeah sorry, see my edit. Signature is a DB column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is for a method that you could use instead of `save`. It checks if a model exists with the same signature. If it finds one, it updates that existing model with the attributes and then return that model. If there is no other model that has that signature, it will continue on saving. You will have to use this in place of ActiveRecord's `#save` in places where you want this behavior. There was no way to do this using callbacks since the only way to cancel saving in a callback was to have it return false.

```
def save_signature
  model = Model.find_by(signature: signature)
  if model
    model.update(attributes)
    model
  else
    save
  end
end
```

Let me know if I understood what you wanted. If not, then just point out what I misunderstood and I'd be happy to change my answer accordingly.

Comment: But this will either throw an error or return false. I would like to return the original model...

Comment: `false` in a before_save does not throw an error. It will just mean that the model will not continue with saving so it will not make any changes to itself.

Comment: Yes. It will if you call a bang method like `save!`.

Comment: You're right. Changed my answer and replaced `false`. The `signature` attribute will then be set back to its original value.

Comment: Is my answer solving the problem you have? Is there anything else lacking?

Comment: We're getting there, however the current answer will still save the new model. I want to update and return the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest way but why to stop the chain?
fetch the object on before_* filter, do the check and update the model, it will be saved with the old value.
what do you think?

Comment: The problem is that the normal command chain will not yield the same result as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Read about find_or_create_by  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by  . This will either create a new record or output you the previous one. Hopefully it may work for you